# Alter table name and store it in a variable in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SET @p := ALTER TABLE table
RENAME COLUMN ID TO p_ID,
RENAME COLUMN c_id to p_c_id;
```

I am trying to alter the column names of a table and wanted to save in a new variable.
I get an error alter is not valid at this expression.
This is what I have tried so far.
I am a newbie and any help us appreciated

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` doesn't return anything that you can assign to a variable. What are you expecting `@p` to be?

Comment: Is there a way to change the column name and set it to another variable without altering the original table?

Comment: I don't even understand what that would mean. Are you asking if you can create alternate names for the column? You could create a view.

Comment: You still haven't clearly explained what you want to save to the variable. What do you expect to see if you do `select @p`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `ALTER TABLE` statement does not return a value. You can't store it.
But if you need this. Then you can try to store the ALTER TABLE statement in a variable as a string. Then, you can use the variable later to log the change or to execute the statement again if necessary.

```
SET @p := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE takes
RENAME COLUMN ID TO p_ID,
RENAME COLUMN course_id to p_course_id;');
```

Like this:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @p;
EXECUTE stmt;
```